# Upload , Resize and Save using PHP (or generating thumbnails)

Tags: php, html

I am making a website for users to be able to track their favorite bands. One of the features of the website is allowing users to upload pictures of any gigs they have been to, they are then saved to a file and image location is stored in the database.

My problem is I need to be able to resize the images upon saving, as the page is taking to long to load when there are many pictures.

I know there are many questions on here like this but i'm just not to sure how to modify the code I have to do this.

Is this the best way to do it or should I use thumbnails? as the images are going to be displayed in a gallery, if there is many then the page is going to load slower

My knowledge of php is limited so any help is appreciated

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
 <?php

  ///UPLOAD IMAGES
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM photouploads WHERE BandID ='$bandid'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql,$connect)or die ($error1);
 $row = mysql_num_rows($result);
     $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))

     {
         $name = $bandid."(".++$row.").jpg";

         $tmp_name=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];

         if ($name)
         {
             //start upload
             $location="Photouploads/".$name;
             if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location))
                  {
                   mysql_query("INSERT INTO photouploads (BandID,UserID,ImageLocation)
                   VALUES ('$bandid', '$userid', '$location')") ;
                  }

         }
else
;

}
```

And my form:

```
        <input type='file' name='photo' id='photo'> 
        <input type='submit' class='submitLink' name='submit' id='submit'value='upload'>
 </form>";
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php

Comment: Thanks for the link but i don't really know how to implement this

Comment: Than you need to learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic PHP image resizing class i've used in the past. You'll need the PHP GD2 module installed and enabled in order for it to work.

Usage:

```
$resized = ImageResizer::resizeExistingImage($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],
                                                                null,
                                                                500,
                                                                500,
                                                                100);
if (!$resized){
    throw new Exception('Could not resize image');
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($resized);
echo '</pre>';
```

The Class:

```
class ImageResizer
{
    const RESULT_RESIZE_NOT_REQUIRED = 'resize_not_required';
    const RESULT_RESIZE_SUCCESSFUL = 'resize_successful';

    private static $_filePath = null;
    private static $_newPath = null;
    private static $_maxwidth = null;
    private static $_maxheight = null;
    private static $_quality = null;

    private static $_newWidth = null;
    private static $_newHeight = null;

    private static $_actualWidth = null;
    private static $_actualHeight = null;

    /**
     * Takes an image (from a file path) and resizes it. The newly resized image
     * can then either be created in a different location, therefore maintainig 
     * the original file. Or can be created in the original location, therefore
     * overwriting the original file.
     * 
     *
     * @static 
     * @access public
     * @param string    $filePath   The file path of the image to resize
     * @param string    $newPath    The file path where the resized image will 
     *                              be created. Null to overwrite original.
     * @param integer   $maxwidth   The maximum height of the resized image
     * @param integer   $maxheight  The maximum width of the resized image
     * @param integer   $quality    The quality of the image 
     */
    public static function resizeExistingImage($filePath, 
                                                $newPath = null, 
                                                $maxwidth = 1000, 
                                                $maxheight = 1000, 
                                                $quality = 100)
    {
        if (is_null($newPath)) {
            $newPath = $filePath;
        }

        $gdImage = getimagesize($filePath);

        $actualWidth = $gdImage[0];
        $actualHeight = $gdImage[1];

        // Do we even need to resize the image!?
        if ($actualWidth <= $maxwidth && $actualHeight <= $maxheight){
            return array('result' => self::RESULT_RESIZE_NOT_REQUIRED,
                            'newHeight' => $actualHeight,
                            'newWidth' => $actualWidth);
        }

        $ratio = $actualWidth / $maxwidth;
        // echo "ratio : ".$ratio."<br />";

        // echo "Current dimensions: ".$actualWidth." : ".$actualHeight." : <br />";

        // set the defaults:
        $newWidth = intval($actualWidth);
        $newHeight = intval($actualHeight);     

        if ($actualWidth > $maxwidth) {
            $newWidth = intval($maxwidth);
            $newHeight = intval($actualHeight / $ratio);
        }

        // echo "After width process, dimensions: ".$newWidth." : ".$newHeight." : <br />";

        // once we've got the size width, is the height now small enough? 
        if ($newHeight > $maxheight) {
            // set a new ratio
            $ratio = $newHeight / $maxheight;
            $newWidth = intval($newWidth / $ratio);
            $newHeight = intval($maxheight);
        }       

        // echo "New dimensions: ".$newWidth." : ".$newHeight." : <br />";

        // Assign the class vars
        self::$_filePath = $filePath;
        self::$_newPath = $newPath;
        self::$_maxwidth = $maxwidth;
        self::$_maxheight = $maxheight;
        self::$_quality = $quality;

        self::$_newWidth = $newWidth;
        self::$_newHeight = $newHeight;

        self::$_actualWidth = $actualWidth;
        self::$_actualHeight = $actualHeight;

        switch (strtolower($gdImage['mime'])) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                self::_createFromJpeg();
                break;
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                self::_createFromPJpeg();
                break;
            case 'image/png':
                self::_createFromPng();
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                self::_createFromGif();
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception('Mime Type \'' . $gdImage['mime'] . '\' not supported');
                break;
        }

        return array('result' => self::RESULT_RESIZE_SUCCESSFUL,
                        'newHeight' => $newHeight,
                        'newWidth' => $newWidth);

    }

    /**
     * Resizes images of type image/jpeg.
     *
     * @static 
     * @access private
     * @return void
     */
    private static function _createFromJpeg()
    {
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg(self::$_filePath);

        $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor(self::$_newWidth, self::$_newHeight);

        imagecopyresampled($new_img, 
                            $img, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            self::$_newWidth, 
                            self::$_newHeight, 
                            self::$_actualWidth, 
                            self::$_actualHeight);

        imagejpeg($new_img, self::$_newPath, self::$_quality);
    }

    /**
     * Resizes images of type image/jpeg.
     *
     * @static 
     * @access private
     * @return void
     */
    private static function _createFromPJpeg()
    {
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg(self::$_filePath);

        imageinterlace($img, 1);

        $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor(self::$_newWidth, self::$_newHeight);

        imagecopyresampled($new_img, 
                            $img, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            self::$_newWidth, 
                            self::$_newHeight, 
                            self::$_actualWidth, 
                            self::$_actualHeight);

        imagejpeg($new_img, self::$_newPath, self::$_quality);
    }

    /**
     * Resizes images of type image/png.
     *
     * @static 
     * @access private
     * @return void
     */
    private static function _createFromPng()
    {
        $img = imagecreatefrompng(self::$_filePath);

        $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor(self::$_newWidth, self::$_newHeight);

        imagecopyresampled($new_img, 
                            $img, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            self::$_newWidth, 
                            self::$_newHeight, 
                            self::$_actualWidth, 
                            self::$_actualHeight);

        imagepng($new_img, self::$_newPath);        
    }

    /**
     * Resizes images of type image/gif.
     *
     * @static 
     * @access private
     * @return void
     */
    private static function _createFromGif()
    {
        $img = imagecreatefromgif(self::$_filePath);

        $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor(self::$_newWidth, self::$_newHeight);

        imagecopyresampled($new_img, 
                            $img, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            self::$_newWidth, 
                            self::$_newHeight, 
                            self::$_actualWidth, 
                            self::$_actualHeight);

        imagegif($new_img, self::$_newPath);    
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving *all* the data to find a name for the new image is very innefficient. A better solution would be insert a record without storing the filename and generate the filename from the auto_increment id (using a base path /some/where/Photouploads/$bandid/).

If this is not your biggest performance problem, it soon will be.

Reducing the size of the images is a good idea too - as is checking for duplicates.

> if there is many then the page is going to load slower

Defer loading of images below the fold - there are lots of ready made scripts to do this ([e.g.](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload))